# How do I create a variable in Javascript, and add a changing number to the variable's name?

Tags: javascript

This code is completely wrong, but I hope it gives you the idea of what I'm going for:

```
var qarowquestion+obj.returnIntJson;
```

obj.returnIntJson's value is just an integer. I want to take the value held there, for example: 2043,  and add 2043 to the end of qarowquestion. Thus, I would have:

```
var qarowquestion2043;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TGH's reply was almost what I needed, or it is and I just don't know how to use it.

I changed it so that the part with the number is the value, not the key.

```
    var myObj = {};
    myObj['qarowquestion'] = "qarowquestion" + obj.returnIntJson;
```

Now, I can access it with: `myObj.qarowwquestion` which gives such result: `qarowquestion2043`

And for a specific example, in my case:

```
document.getElementById("qarow" + obj.returnIntJson).innerHTML = myObj.qarowquestion;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['qarowquestion' + obj.returnIntJson] = 'some Val';
```

Try the above. It will take advantage of dynamic javascript and create a qarowquestion2043 property on the myObj object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create variable, As TGH mentioned you can add your values as a named properties inside an object.

```
var obj = {};
obj['qarowquestion' + obj.returnIntJson] = 'xxx';
```

By this way you can give proper namespace also for your objects.

```
var someNameSpace = {};
someNameSpace['someObject'] = 'someVal';
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript) on using dynamic variable names in javascript and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117172/1083314) brings up a very good point (emphasis is mine):

> Since ECMA-/Javascript is all about **Objects** and **Contexts** (which, are also somekind of Object), every variable is stored in a such called Variable- (or in case of a Function, Activation Object).In the Global scope (= NO function context), you implicitly write those variables into the Global object (= window in a browser).

So for example (again taken from the answer):

```
function foobar() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;

 var name = window['a']; // === undefined as it refers to the global context and is undefined
 alert(name);
 name = this['a']; // === 1
 alert(name); // outputs 1
 alert(a); //outputs 1

//Since we are talking about context here, you could clearly do

this['qarowquestion'+obj.returnIntJson] = "foo";
alert(qarowquestion2043); //outputs foo
}
```

So in essence, variables can be accessed as objects in specific contexts which can be really helpful.